# Declaring External Decimal in Cobol

Tags: cobol

Looking for solution on my problem. The values I need to convert was in alphanumeric.

```
05 WS-NUM-TX.
05 WS-NUM  PIC P9(04).
05 WS-NUM1 PIC P9(03).
05 WS-NUM2 PIC P9(03).

MOVE '0001 222217' TO WS-NUM-TX.
MOVE WS-NUM-TX(1:4) TO WS-NUM.
MOVE WS-NUM-TX(6:3) TO WS-NUM1.
MOVE WS-NUM-TX(9:3) TO WS-NUM2.
```

I did `COMPUTE WS-NUM = FUNCTION NUMVAL(WS-NUM-TX)` for this to be numeric.

Now, the problem is, I need this values as decimal for computation. Need help to convert this values to become `.0001,  .222 and .217` however the declaration
I did for external decimal displayed with no decimal point. Please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The `P` in the `PICTURE` clause is an error, as is the absence of a `PICTURE` clause for `WS-NUM-TX`. (As of the the 4th revision.)

Possibly,

```
05 WS-NUM-TX PIC X(11).
05 WS-NUM  PIC .9(04).
05 WS-NUM1 PIC .9(03).
05 WS-NUM2 PIC .9(03).

MOVE '0001 222217' TO WS-NUM-TX.
COMPUTE WS-NUM = FUNCTION NUMVAL (WS-NUM-TX(1:4)) / 10000.
COMPUTE WS-NUM1 = FUNCTION NUMVAL (WS-NUM-TX(6:3)) / 1000.
COMPUTE WS-NUM2 = FUNCTION NUMVAL (WS-NUM-TX(9:3)) / 1000.
```

---

Based on the original post (revisions 1 and 2) with additional editing.

```
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 FILLER.
       05 WS-NUM-TX.
           07 WS-NUM-TX1 PIC 9(4).
           07 FILLER     PIC X.
           07 WS-NUM-TX2 PIC 9(3).
           07 WS-NUM-TX3 PIC 9(3).
       05 WS-NUM  PIC .9(04).
       05 WS-NUM1 PIC .9(03).
       05 WS-NUM2 PIC .9(03).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   BEGIN.
       MOVE '0001 222217' TO WS-NUM-TX.
       DIVIDE WS-NUM-TX1 BY 10000 GIVING WS-NUM.
       DIVIDE WS-NUM-TX2 BY 1000 GIVING WS-NUM1.
       DIVIDE WS-NUM-TX3 BY 1000 GIVING WS-NUM2.
       DISPLAY WS-NUM
       DISPLAY WS-NUM1
       DISPLAY WS-NUM2
       STOP RUN
       .
```

Output:

```
.0001
.222
.217
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `V` in the picture clause. This determines the position of the comma.
For example: `PIC 9(05)V9(03)` will result in 00000,000

Source: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/ref/rlddesym.htm